# Strange behaviour of seq.nth in exists-expression

Tags: z3, smt

Running z3 on this

```
(assert (< (seq.nth (seq.unit 0) 0) 0))
(check-sat)
```

has UNSAT as a result

But running

```
(assert (exists ((x Int))
  (< (seq.nth (seq.unit 0) x) 0)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

is SAT. Looking at the model

```
(model 
  (define-fun seq.nth_u ((x!0 Seq) (x!1 Int)) Int
    (- 1))
)
```

So, doesn't this mean that seq.nth is treated like a variable over a Function?
Shouldn't it be a constant function (returning always the indexed value of seq)?

I would expect the second case also to be UNSAT. In order to achieve that, how can I make seq.nth a non-variable-function?

Help appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

The function `seq.nth` is underspecified. That is, if you query an element that is out-of-bounds (i.e., either at a negative index or at at an index that is larger than the last), then it is free to return whatever value the solver wants. (And the solver will always pick a value to make your query satisfiable.)

This is typical of SMTLib, where underspecified functions can simply take any value when given arguments that are not in the domain of their arguments. So, z3 is telling you that there is such a model by indexing out-of-bounds using the sequence `(seq.unit 0)`. i.e., we can index it at some negative value, or at some index larger than `0`.

Note that the value of `seq.nth_u` given in the model (note the `_u` suffix!) is indicative of how the underflow/overflow behavior is modeled. It should not be confused with the value of the function `seq.nth`.

You can actually get z3 to display the value of the index `x` if you make it a top-level existential:

```
(declare-fun x () Int)

(assert (< (seq.nth (seq.unit 0) x) 0))

(check-sat)
(get-value (x))
```

For this, z3 says:

```
sat
((x (- 1)))
```

that is, index at location `-1`. But do not confuse this with the `-1` that you see in the interpretation of `seq.nth_u`. In fact, if we also add:

```
(assert (> x 0))
```

then z3 says:

```
sat
((x 1))
```

However, if we add:

```
(assert (>= x 0))
(assert (<  x 1))
```

then we get `unsat` as expected. And when working with sequences, you should add these sorts of constraints (if possible!) to avoid out-of-bounds accesses.

Comment: But in the exists expression we have (seq.unit 0). This sequence should be fixed having 0 at index 0 and not -1. Also any other index is fixed undefined. Am I getting things wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I misread your original question. Should be more clear now.